# Certain letters are suddenly showing up as fractions in Mac's Mail program

Tags: macos, fonts, character-encoding, apple-mail

Certain letters are suddenly showing up as fractions in Mac's Mail program.  Specifically,

- lowercase a = 1/2
- lowercase b = 1/4
- lowercase c = 3/4

Capitalized, they work fine, the other keys are working fine, and this only happens with this particular program, but I can't figure out what to change or what's wrong.

It's Mac OS X 10.4.11 and an update was applied last night but other than that nothing's been changed (that I know of, I'm asking for someone else).

Thanks.

Comment: Oops, you were right, I changed "problem" to "program".  Also, I did restart it, the updates required a restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it was something that was solved by changing some settings and rebooting.

The particular emails he was looking at were from China, so I think something got lost in the character encoding on the way.  I set the program to always reply in plaintext, and that seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have a different font accidentally selected?

Comment: +1, Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.